# ImageView scale issues

Tags: android

I have an ImageView (original size: 500 x 80) . I am changing its width parameter like this:

```
imageView1.getLayoutParams().width=(int) (500.0*width_proc);
```

When I use `ImageView.getWidth()` the result is 555, which is perfect.

When I use `ImageView.getHeight()` the result is still 80. It doesn't update to the new value, even though the image is automatically rescaled.

I tried to add a `Sleep(100)`, to use `ImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener`, or to add `measure()` functions, nothing works.

Code looks like this:

...

```
    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View myView=this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
              public void onGlobalLayout() {
                  BuildGraphInterface();
             }
          });
    }
```

........

```
public void BuildGraphInterface()
{
   .......
   //================= search 1 ===========================//
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    imageView1.getLayoutParams().width=(int) (500.0*width_proc);
    imageView1.requestLayout();
    imageView1.invalidate();

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    textView1.setText( " " + imageView1.getHeight() + " " + imageView1.getWidth() );
   .......
}
```

Comment: what makes you think that it should keep aspect ratio? you are changing the Width, how would that affect the height?

Comment: Because it's visible. When I  make width = 300 , on the screen it will be a smaller rectangle with the same ratio :)

Comment: It might be helpful to see the XML layout that is creating the ImageView -- for example, is the height wrap_content or is it set to exactly 80 pixels?  Also, what scaleType are you using?  In any case, Daniel Bo is basically on the right track -- changing the width of a View does not necessarily cause changes to its height.

Comment: In my opinion, I thought when I change width value, he rescale automatically, because visual is what it does. If I change the width, the rectangle gets smaller or bigger with the same ratio. In XML I set fix proportion of width and height (500,80).